# Category of Modules over the semi-ring of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, category-theory, modules

I am wondering if there exists a category of modules over the semi-ring of the complex numbers.

Comment: Yes, why not? Over any semiring.

Comment: There is a category of modules over $\mathbb C$ (usually called $\mathbb C$-vector spaces) and there is a category of *semi*-modules for any given semiring. What are you talking about when you say "semiring of complex numbers" if not the field of complex numbers?

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, I mean the field of complex numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering if there exists a category of modules over the semi-ring of the complex numbers.
>   @rschwieb Yes, I mean the field of complex numbers.

Yes: there is a category of modules for any given ring. Two categories in fact: the right modules and the left modules.

You usually call the category of $\mathbb C$ modules "the category of vector spaces over $\mathbb C$."